# How to define __dirname while running a node.js backend script on the browser side?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting the error while running the script in the browser side. The error is 'Uncaught ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined'. I tried using const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(URL)); in the below query but it's not working. Can anyone help to fix this issue?

```
var fs= require(['fs']);
var path= require(['path']);
dName=path.dirname;
URL=path.fileURLToPath;
//import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(URL));

var fname= "config.json"
var jPath= path.join(__dirname,"..","ConfigGen","Config",fname);
var jsString= fs.readFileSync(jPath, 'utf8')

var tType= "cto"                        //Get this from input
var pth= JSON.parse(jsString)[tType]    //perform error handling

var cType = "jbod"                      //Get this from input
//Use that path 
fs.readdir(pth, function(err,files) {
    files.forEach(function(file){
        fName= cType+"_"+tType+"_uut.yaml-example";
        if(file==fName){
            var flContent= fs.readFileSync(path.join(pth,file),"utf8")
            console.log(flContent)
        }
    })
})
```

Note: Its running fine in the node. Throwing error in the browser(I am running in Chrome)

Comment: Why would you expect this code to run in the browser? I mean, it's a Node.js code - meant to be run on the server, it's not compatible with the browser. We need more details about your case, like what are you trying to achieve, what have you tried/done so far. (maybe you use browserify-like tool or something?)

Comment: Without any more details what I can tell is that `__dirname` is a Node.js variable and its value is the directory name of the current module. It's available in the Node.js environment only and cannot be used in the browser (unless you will define `__dirname` yourself but it won't be the same variable)